# How to post model with kendo window refresh?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, kendo-ui, window, mode

How to pass model with Kendo Window refresh option ?

I am using below code for that in my partial view:-

```
var proWindow = $("#productWindow").data("kendoWindow");
   proWindow.refresh({            
       url: "../../Product/UpdateProduct",
       type: "POST",
       contentType:"application/json",
       data: { prodModel: $("form").serialize()
   });
```

And below is the code for Controller:-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateProduct(ProductMaintViewModel prodModel)
{

}
```

> > But i am getting null on my model parameter in controller.

Can any one have any idea about that,means how we can post the whole model with kendo window refresh data option in jquery/javascript ?

FYI, i am working on ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

Below is my ProductMaintViewModel class :-

```
public class ProductMaintViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int? InsuranceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Remote("CheckProductName", "Product", ErrorMessage = "Product Name already exists.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsDraft { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Product Type")]
    public int? SelectedProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductTypes { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Customer Type")]
    public int? SelectedCustomerSubTypeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CustomerSubTypes { get; set; }      

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableLabor { get; set; } 


}
```

Comment: Please show us your ProductMaintViewModel.class

Comment: Can you put a break point on your set methods in the ProductMaintViewModel.class and see if they get called? MVC will try to set the properties found on the form. You can also add a default constructor to your class to see if that gets called. Also, i would like to see the html on your form.

Comment: Are you able to pass a simple variable instead of the whole model?

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateProduct([FromBody]ProductMaintViewModel prodModel)
{
    enter code here
}
```

If anyone is still reading this or has any troubles with a similar situation in the future, anotating the model with [FromBody] (example above) will parse the model correctly, assuming of course the JSON from the post request matches the model naming conventions. Also, setting the contentType to application/json is a crucial part of the header for this to work. Hope it helps someone in the future